# retrieve an image from database using linQ by asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to get image from database using `asp.net` and `linq` 
I want to make a page when the user enter that page he see an image

```
Professor_Dim prof = sdc.Professor_Dims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.P_ID == 0);

if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0) {
  string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
  byte[] fileByte = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
  Binary binaryObj = new Binary(fileByte);
  prof.P_Image = binaryObj;
  sdc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

this code upload the image to database i want to retrieve that image in another page

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.net MVC**

I did it a little bit different. I stored the byteData as is in the database and then did the following:

```
Bitmap bmp;

        byte[] img = //retrieve bytes from DB

        if (img == null)
            return new EmptyResult();

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img))
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
        }
```

If you're using ASP MVC you can return an ImageResult where you place the bmp as the Image and use for example for the ImageFormat ImageFormat.Jpeg.

**ASP.NET**

```
byte[] bytes = //retrieve the Image bytes from the database;
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
```

Comment: If you're using ASP MVC you can place it in the action of the controller that will show the page or that get's loaded from that page

Comment: Let me elaborate.. if you're using ASP MVC you could create a separate action for retrieving the image and then do something like this:
`<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayPicture","Registration")/@picture.Id?thumbnail=true" width="128px"/>`
You will need to return a ImageResult in that case.

Comment: Then I would suggest:
`byte[] bytes = //retrieve imagebytes from DB
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;`

You can do this on the page where you want to display the image

Comment: Make sure the image you upload is a jpeg else you need to adapt the extension. And that your image is called Image1:
`<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />`